# Choosing an appropriate part of an unreliable dataset

Tags: regression, modeling, robust, measurement-error

I have a dataset with $\approx2000$ entries (for example, model of car).

For each car model I know the weight of the car, and the power output. I don't know the price or age, which is likely to affect the power to weight ratio of the car. I have a reasonable amount of faith in the data, but some manufacturers might fib a bit (maybe 5% of the data is unreliable).

**How can I determine, in a defensible way, the best power output for a given weight of car?**

I'm mathematically literate to an engineering undergraduate level, but don't have any statistics experience beyond high school.

I've thought of the following:

- Sort cars by power/weight ratio and then take the top $n\%$. Problem is the determination of $n$.
- Graph the data and plot a trendline through it. This will underestimate the best power output by a large factor.
- Take the best power to weight ratio and just use that. Problem is that power to weight ratios do not necessarily scale linearly with car weight (it may be easier to produce a small car with a high power to weight ratio for example).
- Bin the data into weight categories, then do the same as above. Problem is that taking a single datapoint from an unreliable dataset doesn't seem right.
- As above, but trying to cross-check the data against outside information (for example, magazine performance tests). This information isn't available for all cars, so probably unfeasible.

For my curiosity, what is the name of these class of problems? It seems like something that would occur commonly, but I don't know how to search for it. Is there an English to Statistics translation tool somewhere?

Comment: What does "best" mean in the context of your question? Do you want to know the average power to weight ratio, or the manner in which power varies as a function of weight, something else? You also need a model of the error, eg, is it that values might be rounded off by up to 5%, or that 95% of the data is veridical, but 5% has been distorted (how so)?

Comment: I don't really see why power should scale neatly with weight, except by convention - you can put a 1L engine in a truck, or put an extremely powerful engine in an ultra lightweight F1 car. What are you trying to show? Perhaps a plot might help. I don't know if there's a name for the class of problems you're thinking of, but *[robust statistics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robust_statistics)* deal with data that are known to have unusual distributions, or with known outliers.

Comment: **What does "best" mean in the context of your question?**

Comment: By best I mean the highest power to weight ratio in my dataset for a given vehicle weight. I'm not sure whether power/weight does scale with weight or not - for example, vehicle volume will increase linearly with mass, whereas frontal area available for cooling will scale as the root of mass. I'd like to try and obtain a linear model for how power/weight varies with weight. Thank-you both commenters for your suggestions so far. (Apparently comments can only be edited for five minutes, hence previous comment).